# Copying the path to current line

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In phpstorm, using ctrl+alt+c you can copy the path to the current file (`D:/foo/bar.php`). Is there any way to add the current line number to it: `D:/foo/bar.php:22`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `ctrl+alt+shift+c` does the trick.

Also see: this: https://github.com/kstenschke/referencer-plugin 
It uses Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C twice to showing a list of references to be copied.